# How to set QRect in the center of cell in QListVIew with QAbstractItemDelegate’s paint?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt5, qstyleditemdelegate

I have QListVIew and delegate to paint the list view. I paint some text int the center of cell.
so I do it:

```
void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyledOptionViewItem        &option, const QModelIndex &index )
{
.
.
.
QRect textRect(option.rect.center(),QSize(option.rect.width(),option.rect.height());

paiter->drawText(textRect,text,QTextOption());
```

but it starts to paint from the center. how can I center this output?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's starting to draw from the centre, because you're telling it to start the object from the centre. Your construction of the `QRect`:

```
QRect textRect(option.rect.center(),QSize(option.rect.width(),option.rect.height());
```

Is calling [`QRect(QPoint topLeft, QSize size)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrect.html#QRect-3).

What I think you want to do, is move the centre of your rectangle to the point that you've set as its top-left, something like:

```
textRect.moveCenter(option.rect.center());
```

Comment: textRect.moveCenter(option.rect.center()) doesn't center the rect to the center, why?